# Rounding a double and grouping it?

Tags: java

I'll explain this the best I can.

Let's say I get a user input and that is: 245, I want this to be rounded down to 200 then divided by 100 and then finally +1 so the outcome is 3 (putting it in zone 3, more below)

Basically what I need is a zoning system that goes as follows

```
Zone 1: 0-99
Zone 2: 100-199
Zone 3: 200-299
```

And so on for whatever number the user enters, so I feel rounded the number down then dividing it by 100 will be the best way to do this as I currently have it with if else statements although obviously that is finite and will only work with my predetermined zones.

Comment: Is it possible for the user input to be 300 or greater?

Answer (score 9):

Why not just divide it by 100 to start with? That will do the rounding (always towards 0) if you start off with an integer:

```
int zone = (input / 100) + 1;
```

There's no need to get into non-integer arithmetic at all here. If the user input is actually as a `double`, you can just cast:

```
int zone = ((int) input / 100) + 1;
```

Comment: Jon, You are really fast :)

Comment: Thanks alot! I said this on the answer below, you were both so speedy to reply I wasnt expecting that! My question is what happens if the user inputs 254.1 for example? Can I discard this decimal or will it do it automatically?

Comment: since zone is an int type. It would ignore anything after decimal, so you don't have to worry about it

Comment: @user134613: You haven't told us anything about how the user is entering a value... but if you *do* have it as a `double`, you can just cast to `int` to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy as this:

```
int input = ...
int zone = input / 100 + 1;
```

In java integer division discards the fraction.

Comment: Thanks! However what happens if the user inputs 254.1 for example? Can I discard this decimal or will it do it automatically?

Comment: @user134613 if `input` is a `double` then you'd have to cast it to `int` within the calculation or cast the result to a `int` afterwards, depending on when you want the rounding/cut-off to happen.

Comment: It will be discarded "automatically". Dividing 0 - 99 by 100 is always less than 1, so you get 0 as a result. Dividing 100 - 199 is always greater than or equal to 1 but less than 2. Hence you get 1 as a result. And so forth ...

Answer (score 0):

To get a more general solution that handles a wider range of integers (and floating point numbers like 54.2 too):

```
int(log(n))+1
where n is the number typed in and log is log base 10
```

For example (works for smaller numbers too):

```
n=5044
log(n)=3.7027750779010440114183447590569
int(log(5044))=3
int(log(n))+1=4
Zone is 4
```

Comment: That doesn't satisfy the criteria that the OP has specified though. We don't know what has led to the requirements for these "zones" but I don't think it's a good idea to expect that you can arbitrarily change them - nor that the OP *needs* to handle values beyond `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - good point, but problem title states it needs to handle floating point numbers too **Rounding a double and grouping it?** - OP makes no statement about how many Zones there are only **And so on for whatever number the user enters** - what about negative numbers which, using the divide by 100 method, give an answer with a decimal point. My answer doesn't work for negative numbers either though.

Comment: There's no indication that negative numbers *need* to be handled - and no indication that floating point numbers need to be handled beyond the simple "round towards zero and divide by 100". My reading of the question is that it's asking for an *implementation* of the current plan, not a new plan.

Comment: So what does **whatever number the user enters** mean?